# 'ambiguous redirect' error from Bash

Tags: bash, io-redirection, cat, brace-expansion

I have three directories a,b,c and each have a file named *old.txt*

I would like to copy the contents of the file *new.txt* to each of these files. My approach is

```
$ cat < new.txt > {a,b,c}/old.txt
```

But I'm getting

```
bash: {a,b,c}/old.txt: ambiguous redirect
```

Why? How it can be done with Cat and Brace Expansion in a single command ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bash can't do redirections to multiple targets as splitting the output would require an intermediate process to read from the command and write to all the targets. (Zsh has builtin support for that, though.)

You can use the [`tee` utility](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html) to do it:

```
tee {a,b,c}/old.txt  < new.txt > /dev/null
```

Comment: what if I want to append to the input to {a,b,c}/old.txt

Comment: @Neo_Returns Then use `tee -a`

Comment: So, we can not do it with **<<**

Comment: @Neo_Returns, no, `<<` starts a here-document (see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html)). `tee` writes to the files it got as arguments, and follows the usual custom of using options like `-a` to control what it does.